# Facebook SDK on Android show a public Site

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

**What I'm trying to do**

---

Hello and good Morning Guys, I'd like to create an Facebook-Viewer witch only show's me one specified Site for example this one here: [Some Random Facebook Site](http://www.facebook.com/LavishZH) Because I didn't know how to do this, I was taking a look at the Facebook API site, which gave me no Information....

**Question**

---

So as you probably pinnend, I have no clue how to do this. It would be great if you can tell me following:

1. Do I need a Developer Key for this?
2. And could you provide me some Sample-Code or a good tutorial.

Some additional Information, the Facebook-Site I'd like to show is public (so I don't want that the user has to log in into fb).

Thx for you anwsers in advance!

Best Regards

safari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution for the Problem**

---

I figured out a solution witch works in my case. What needs to be present:

1. Register your App on [Facebook Developers](http://developers.facebook.com)
2. The Page needs to be published and public
3. Get de APP_ID and APP_SECRET out of your registered App, with those you can get the Access Token like following `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id="+APP_ID+"&client_secret="+APP_SECRET`

Here's the Code for it:

---

```
    private static final String ACCESS_TOKEN_QUERY = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id="+APP_ID+"&client_secret="+APP_SECRET;

        private static final String FEED_URL = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+PAGE_ID+"/feed?";
        private static String accesstoken = "";
        private static String jsonresponse = "";

        Context context;


            String line = null;

            final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> videolist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            //Get AccessToken
            try{
                URL url = new URL(ACCESS_TOKEN_QUERY); 

                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

                //read d response till d end
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    accesstoken = sb.toString();
                    Log.v("log_tag", "Append String " + accesstoken);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                    }


            //Get JSON

            try{
                URL url = new URL(FEED_URL+accesstoken);

                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    jsonresponse = sb.toString();
                    Log.v("log_tag", "Append String " + jsonresponse);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                }
//Here you got the jsonresponse now, with which you can go on.
```

---

The good thing is you don't even need to have the Facebook SDK in your App.
Best Regards

safari

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think you can try and you would need and developer key and would have to create an Facebook application that. You can read this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/) to see how thats done.

Once you have it then you can use `FQL` to get the list of pages. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461509/android-and-facebook-how-to-use-facebook-query-language-fql-out-of-android-ap) give you info about how to make `FQL` query from android App using the Facebook android SDK.

Now the object that you want is [Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/). You can make query using what ever parameter suits your need. randomize the result and show the page using `Facebook graph API.`

Comment: is it like that also possible to see the public statusupdates and photogallerys ?

Comment: I think there is no general concept of public status updates in Facebook (you can explore little more on the Facebook graph API and FQL API and prove me wrong). But you can always check the status message of an particular user (if you know their ID) using the graph or FQL API...

Comment: so like this its only possible to get to those statusupdates from that page, if the page is using de graph or FQL API... If yes its pritty shitty, I should have been a X-Mas present.... :P

Comment: sorry could not understand you last comment. Graph API and the FQL API can be used to access any object, data on the Facebook. Facebook treat everything as object. I would suggest exploring more on the Facebook API..